# Formatting Output to Currency

Tags: c#

I need to format Gtotals output to currency how can I accomplish this. I just grabbed a quick snippet from my code it is not in order.

```
 string Lname, Fname, Depart, Stat, Sex, Salary, cDept, cStat, cSex;
 double Gtotal;


 fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                    Lname = fields[0];
                    Fname = fields[1];
                    Depart = fields[2];
                    Stat = fields[3];
                    Sex = fields[4];
                    Salary = fields[5];

                    Fname = fields[1].TrimStart(null);
                    Depart = fields[2].TrimStart(null);
                    Stat = fields[3].TrimStart(null);
                    Sex = fields[4].TrimStart(null);
                    Salary = fields[5].TrimStart(null);

                    Gtotal = double.Parse(Salary); //convert this to currency? ie. $56,000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "C" format specifier.

```
Gtotal.ToString("C0");
```

will format the value with no decimal places. You can also use the culture info to override the current culture to get different currency symbols if necessary.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: for some reason it wont work I've tried this, is it because its reading from a file?

Comment: @Michael - what value does `Gtotal` have and what string do you get? The source of the data shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

`Gtotal.ToString("C")`